# How can I get excel to stop updating currency exchange rates?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set up an expenses sheet for a team I am running. We compete in both Canada and the US so have expenses in both currencies.  I use `=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDCAD")` and `=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:CADUSD")` so when I enter an expense in one currency, I get the current exchange rate.

I would like to be able to make it so expenses are pegged at the exchange rate on the date the money was spent.  How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from finding the value, then copy/pasting just the values that came up? (Using paste special + values only)

Comment: I will share an example of the document in a moment.  I don't think that would work given how I have formatted the columns.

Comment: 1) this formula does not exist on Excel, please remove the tag.  2) there are optional criteria where you can set the date: `=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDCAD","price",date(2016,4,11))`  However this does return an array so it may not work.

Comment: Apologies for the misused tag; I think of google sheets and excel as interchangeable which I know I shouldn't.  I will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to lock it to the close of a specific date:

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDCAD","price",date(2016,4,11)),2,2)
```

To break it down:

```
GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDCAD","price",date(2016,4,11))
```

Returns an array with 4 cells in a 2 x 2 array.  The value we want is in the bottom right cell.

We use INDEX to find that value.